# traffic shaping for certain (local) users

Tags: iptables, traffic, linux-networking, traffic-shaping, tc

i'm using ubuntu 10.10

i've a local backup user called "backup". :)

i would like to give this user just a bandwidth of 1Mbit. No matter which software wants to connect to the network.

this solution limits:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j MARK --set-mark 12
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j MARK --set-mark 12

tc qdisc del dev eth0 root
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 2 htb default 1
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 2: protocol ip pref 2 handle 12 fw classid 2:6
tc class add dev eth0 parent 2: classid 2:6 htb rate 10Kbit ceil 1Mbit

tc qdisc show dev eth0
tc class show dev eth0
tc filter show dev eth0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be done with tc, but [how can I limit per user bandwidth?](https://serverfault.com/questions/52027/) may be a good starting point.